# Random data in custom field - what might be the cause

Tags: apex, custom-field

Our client's organization is having an issue with a custom comment field. After approving a report, some dodge data might be inserted into that field. The dodge data is tagged code which looks like this:

```
</script></span></th><td class="dataCol last">
```

So it shouldn't be user error. This issue is quite intermittent. Among thousands of records it only happened four times. I tried but still didn't figure out how to replicate the issue.

The interesting part is I searched the whole project and don't see any custom code updating that field. The field is in a Visualforce page but the controller just saved the result into the server without adding any logic. I checked the field updates as well and doesn't see anything related. Any idea what might be the cause?

Update this: 
I looked at the script in the comment. It contains code like this: `sfdcPage.setHelp('01I900000013hPL.00N90000004jkMM', 'The proposed/balloted or voted status for this joining member.');`

However, this help text is set in the custom field definition by the declarative way. So it seems to me that this script is generated by Salesforce itself. But is there any reason it comes to the field.

Comment: I'd say there is some javascript (check static resources maybe) that is inserting some value into that field in the  visualforce page, though the value is not properly escaped string...

Comment: Thank you for that. But I don't see any script calling, or static resource referenced in that VF page - except for an image. Can javascript be called by some other source?

Comment: I have checked the custom components as well - doesn't seem to have any

Comment: I think you should enable field tracking history on that field and wait to happen again to see which user when changed the value. It could be data loader, manual copy-paste mistake, code, anything...

Comment: I am thinking about this as well - But this happens at a really low chance - it happened only four times in the past thousands of records. I am not sure whether we can capture this.

Comment: You might have some malformed HTML that is allowing markup to bleed into an input section. Do any of the records that the page will display have special characters, angled brackets, single quotes etc?

Comment: @BobBuzzard yes, they are all malformed tagged scripts